# capturing attribute _POST['attribute'] value in yii controller

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii

after a long research found this simple CjuiCode which is fetching the names in autocomplete text field perfectly..but can anyone pls tell me how to capture the id for this name in autocomplete textfield in controller???

thanks in advance..

```
<div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->hiddenField($typeModel,'id'); ?>
        <?php

        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',
                        array('model' => $typeModel,
                                'attribute' => 'name',
                                'source' => array_keys(CHtml::listData($typeModel->findAll(array('select' => 'name')), 'name', 'id')),
                                'options' => array(
                                'minLength' => '1',
                               )
                            ));


    ?>


    </div>
```

Im trying something like this but the value is not coming up in controller

```
var_dump($_POST['TypeModel']['id']);die;
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? 'cause I got lost? you want the id after the user has submitted the form? what does it have to do with the autocomplete widget?

Comment: i need to capture the id but i'm displaying name in autocomplete textfield. when i'm clicking on submit i'm able to get other field values except this hidden id in my controller..

Comment: what's the generated html for that hidden field?

Comment: this is how i'm not getting id but other field values are coming..
array(4) {
  ["r"]=>
  string(14) "Model/create"
  ["language"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["Model"]=>
  array(4) {
 
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "new test"
    ["id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["instructions"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["start"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["end"]=>
    string(0) ""
 
  }
  ["ModelType"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Accomodation"
  }
  ["yt0"]=>
  string(6) "Create"
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);die;
```

Comment: Which browser did you used? Look at console and XHR request.

Answer (score 0):

to get hidden field value use followion code in view..

```
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('fieldName','assignValue'); ?>
```

you will get post array with value as...  [fieldName] => assignValue

Comment: thanks for your reply kiran, do i need to use this code in view or form??

Comment: use below code in view,

<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('hiddenField',$typeModel->id); ?>

and when you print post array you will get value in post array.